# Partitioning comments by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a list of `Comment` objects `comments`. Each `Comment` has several properties, one of which is the `date` the comment was posted. I've sorted this list by date and there is at least 1 comment per date in a range.

I would like to loop over `comments` and for every date, create a new list of comments just for that day. However, the way I'm currently doing it feels very inefficient. Is there a more pythonic or efficient way to do this? (I've implemented a `daterange(start_date, end_date)` generator function according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python)):

```
comment_arrays = [] #array of arrays
for d in date_range(date(2015,1,1), date(2016,1,1)):
    day_comments = []
    for c in comments:
        if c.date == d:
            day_comments.append(c)
        else if c.date > d:
            comment_arrays.append(day_comments)
```

Comment: `day_comments` is appended to `comment_arrays` multiple times, is this intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would a great situation to use `itertools.groupby` in.

```
datekey = lambda x: x.date
comments.sort(key=datekey)
date_comments = [list(group) for date, group in itertools.groupby(comments, datekey)]
```

This of course groups all your comments, not only the ones in your date range. I'd use `filter` to skip the ones out of your range if you can't make use of the extra days comments.

Comment: why is the `sort` step needed?

Comment: `groupby` only works properly on sorted lists. If the list is already sorted (which was implied in the question), you don't need to sort again. I just included the `sort` since it's not optional (and it uses the same key function as `groupby`).

Comment: The step and its side effect damage the solution's pythonicity if you ask me. `sorted` would fix the side effect but make another copy of `comments` in memory and still do the extra work.

Comment: Like I said, I only included the `sort` step in my example code because it can use the same key function. If the list is already sorted, it doesn't need to be sorted again (with either `sorted` or `list.sort`).

Answer (score 1):

You are walking `daterange` one time and `comments` many times. Since the latter is, most likely, much longer than the former, it's gonna be more efficient to do the other way round. Besides, `daterange` is homogeneous so it can be accessed by index:

```
startdate=date(2015,1,1)
enddate=date(2016,1,1)
ndays=(enddate-startdate).days+1 #without +1 if the last date shall not be included
comments_by_day=[[] for _ in range(ndays)] 
for c in comments:
    i=c.date-startdate
    try: if i>=0: comments_by_day[i].append(c)  #avoid wraparound behavior
                                                # for negative indices
    except IndexError: pass   # date not in range
```